# Pandas - aggregate values with a variable-length rolling window

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, rolling-computation

The following data frame is used as input:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

json_string = '{"datetime":{"0":1528955662000,"1":1528959255000,"2":1528965487000,"3":1528966204000,"4":1528966289000,"5":1528971637000,"6":1528974438000,"7":1528975251000,"8":1528982200000,"9":1528992569000,"10":1528994282000},"hit":{"0":1,"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5":1,"6":1,"7":0,"8":1,"9":0,"10":1}}'
df = pd.read_json(json_string)
```

The exercise requires you to compute the mean of the `hit` column for each moment in time (`datetime`). However, the current observation should not be included in the mean. For instance, the first observation (index=0) gets `np.NaN` since there are no observations apart from the one we're calculating the mean for. The second observation (index=1) gets 1 since 1/1 = 1 (0 from the second observation is not included). The third observation (index=2) gets 0.5 since (1+0)/2=0.5.

My code provides a correct answer (in terms of numbers) but is not elegant. I wonder whether you can complete the exercise with something different. Is it possible to use the `pandas.api.indexers.VariableOffsetWindowIndexer` or `pandas.api.indexers.BaseIndexer` and then `get_window_bounds()` method?

My solution:

```
def add_hr(df):
    """
    Generate a feature `mean_hr` which represents the average hit rate
    at the moment of making the offer (`datetime`).

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : pandas.DataFrame
        The `hit` column must be present. Ascending/descending order in the `datetime`
        column is not assumed.

        hit : int
        datetime : string (format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    Returns
    ----------
    df_expanded : pandas.DataFrame
        A (deep) copy of the input pandas.DataFrame.
    """

    df_expanded = df.copy(deep=True)

    df_expanded.sort_values(by=['datetime'], ascending=True, inplace=True)

    df_expanded['mean_hr'] = df_expanded['hit'].expanding().mean()

    srs = df_expanded['mean_hr']

    srs = srs[:len(srs)-1]
    srs = pd.concat([pd.Series([np.nan]), srs])
    df_expanded['mean_hr'] = srs.tolist()

    return df_expanded
```

Full disclaimer: The exercise was a part of a recruitment process a month ago. The recruitment is now closed and I can't submit code anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem can be solved by subclassing the `BaseIndexer` class:

```
from pandas.api.indexers import BaseIndexer

class CustomIndexer(BaseIndexer):
    
    def get_window_bounds(self, num_values, min_periods, center, closed, step):
        
        end = np.arange(0, num_values, step, dtype='int64')
        start = np.zeros(len(end), dtype='int64')
                
        return start, end  
    
indexer = CustomIndexer(window_size=0)

df_expanded = df.copy(deep=True)

df_expanded.hit = df_expanded.hit.rolling(indexer).mean()
```

Comment: Somehow I get this error with your answer: ValueError: CustomIndexer does not implement the correct signature for get_window_bounds

Comment: In order for this to work the json sample of the question needs to avoid the datetime parsing via: df = pd.read_json(json_string, convert_dates=False) otherwise the line with rolling raises an exception: DataError: Cannot aggregate non-numeric type: datetime64[ns]

Comment: A better alternative is to restrict the rolling mean just to the hit column via: df_expanded.hit = df_expanded.hit.rolling(indexer).mean()

Answer (score 4):

A simpler version of what you are trying to achieve is simply to shift the index of the expanding mean as below

```py
df.sort_values(by=['datetime'], inplace=True)
df['mean_hit'] = df.expanding().mean().shift(1)
```